# How to populate a table with a foreign key from a dropdown list?

Tags: mysql, php

I am building an event planning application and require some help. To begin the user will create an event. They will then be required to register participants to this event using a user form.

The eventID is a foreign key in the participants table and all participants registered must be associated with a particular event.

So far, I have managed to create a drop down list that shows only the event ids that are already generated. I need to be able to create a participant and select an event id from the dropdown and store these in the participants table. However, I keep receiving the below error message:

Failed. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (event_planner.participants, CONSTRAINT participants_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (eventID) REFERENCES events (eventID) ON UPDATE CASCADE).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<?php
$link=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
mysqli_select_db($link,"event_planner");
?>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Participant's Registration Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body
    <div id="form">
        <form action="partregisterprocess.php" method="POST">

        <h1 align="center">Participant's Registration Page</h1>

        <p>
        Name:<br />
            <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required  />
            </p>

        <p>
        Surname:<br />
            <input type="text" id="surname" name="surname" required  />
            </p>

        <p>
        Date of Birth:<br />
            <input type="date" id="dob" name="dob" required  />
            </p>

        <p>
        Age at Camp:<br />
            <input type="text" id="age" name="age" required />
            </p>

        <p>
        Gender:<br />
            Male<input type="radio" value="male" name="gender"  />
            Female<input type="radio" value="female" name="gender" required />
            </p>

        <p>
        Address:<br />
            <input type="text" id="address" name="address" required />
            </p>


        <p>
        Contact No:<br />
            <input type="text" id="contact" name="contact" required />
        </p>


        <p>
        Next of Kin:<br />
            <input type="text" id="nextkin" name="nextkin" required />
            </p>

        <p>
        Next of Kin's Contact No:<br />
            <input type="text" id="nextContact" name="nextContact" required />
            </p>

        <p>
        Attendance at Camp:<br />
            <input type="text" id="attendcamp" name="attendcamp" required />
            </p>

        <p>
        Attendance at Sunday School:<br />
            <input type="text" id="attendschool" name="attendschool" required />
            </p>

        <p>
        Comments:<br />
            <input type="text" id="comments" name="comments" />
            </p>




        <p>
            <input type="submit" id="btn" value="Register"  />
            </p>


        <label> EventID </label>            
        <id="eventID" name="eventID" /> 


        <select>
<?php
        $res=mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM events");
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
{
?>
         <option><?php echo $row["eventID"]; ?></option>

<?php
}


?> 

    </select>
    </form>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

PROCESS PAGE

```
    <?php

    $Name = $_POST['name'];
    $Surname = $_POST['surname'];
    $Date_of_Birth = $_POST['dob'];
    $Age_at_Camp = $_POST['age'];
    $Gender = $_POST['gender'];
    $Address = $_POST['address'];
    $Contact_No = $_POST['contact'];
    $Next_of_Kin = $_POST['nextkin'];
    $Kin_ContactNo = $_POST['nextContact'];
    $Attendance_Camp = $_POST['attendcamp'];
    $Attendance_School = $_POST['attendschool'];
    $Comments = $_POST['comments'];
    $eventID = $_POST['eventID'];


mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
        mysql_select_db("event_planner");

$insert= mysql_query("INSERT INTO participants VALUES ('','$Name','$Surname','$Date_of_Birth','$Age_at_Camp','$Gender','$Address','$Contact_No','$Next_of_Kin','$Kin_ContactNo','$Attendance_Camp','$Attendance_School','$Comments','$eventID')")
    or die("Failed. ".mysql_error());

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you that you are choosing an EventID which is not in the `events` table.

There are a few things you should do or consider:

1. **Never, ever, write a `mysql_query` using user input without sanitizing (filtering)**. You are opening a very big door to [SQL Injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp). If any user would write the surname *O'Brien* you'd be in for a surprise. If they would write *Ha ha '; drop database ; --* you could very easily get a nasty surprise. Make sure you *sanitize* user's input (by way of [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php), in your case). Or, much better still, use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).
2. You are using [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php), which is deprecated. You are recommended to use then `mysqli` or `PDO` instead. `mysql_query` is not part of PHP 7.0, which is already up and running. Check [Choosing a MySQL API](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).
3. It's not good practice to write `INSERT INTO` statements without column names. If, at any time, you decide to add an extra column to your table, this `INSERT` statement will stop working. And it will stop working at the worst possible moment. It is also more  difficult to check that you're actually putting the right values into the right columns, because you don't have that information. So, `INSERT INTO table (col1, col2, ...)` is not only *future proof* but also *self-documenting*.
4. For debugging purposes, it is always much better to get your SQL statement in a variable (that can be `echoed`, or added to the `die` instruction).

So, to make the minimum number of changes, I'd rather write:

```
$sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO participants (name, surname, event_id) " .
               "                  VALUES ('%s', '%s',    %d)",
               mysql_real_escape_string($Name),
               mysql_real_escape_string($Surname),
               intval($eventID)) ;

$insert = mysql_query($sql) 
    or die("Failed. " . mysql_error() . ".\nSQL was: " . $sql);
```

(You need to add as many columns as needed, with the propoer names; I put three as an example, and assumed names and types)

Answer (score 0):

Do *not* mix `mysql_*` API calls with `mysqli_*`.  Use only the latter!